# Rails, locking record in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locking

I'm trying to lock one of the records in my database when seeding (using API). By locking I mean- not being able to create topics under certain movie or just disable 'show' method.
It'll be simpler if I'll just show you my seeds.rb file:

```
require 'open-uri'

@doc=Nokogiri::XML(open("http://www.kinoballada.info/repertuar/export/small/dzien/xml"))
movie_array = []
@doc.css('dzien').each do |node|
    children=node.children
    movie_array << children.css('tytul').inner_text
    Movie.find_or_create_by(
    :name => children.css('tytul').inner_text
    )
    end
    movies_to_delete = Movie.where.not(name: movie_array)
    movies_to_delete.destroy_all
```

Last 2 rows are essential- I want to LOCK the movie, not destroy it, making something like:

```
    movies_to_lock = Movie.where.not(name: movie_array)
    movies_to_lock.??????_all
```

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: can u be elaborate more what you exactly mean by term LOCK ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you want is to issue a [`select for update`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-select.html) command. Once you select a set of rows, they'll be locked for other threads until you do something that causes the database to release the lock.

Not every RDBMS supports the command, and some older databases will lock the entire table when you select from one of its rows. You'll probably want an RDBMS agnostic solution from the application side that avoids such problems, preserving the freedom to switch databases in the future without additional worries.

Consider adding a `boolean` column called `locked` to your table which you can read before allowing the row to be included in any result set. This approach seems to come at a minimal expense, while allowing you to avoid database specific problems.